# How to partition a lag function over IotHub.ConnectionDeviceId in Azure Stream Analytics?

Tags: cortana-intelligence, azure-stream-analytics

According to this site

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-define-inputs/

there is a property from iot hub that can be used in stream analytics for identify the device. But when I want to used it in a lag function, I get a compile error:

> LAG(brightness, 1, -1) OVER (PARTITION BY IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId LIMIT DURATION(minute, 10)) as lastBrightness,

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should be supported - we will look into why error is thrown.
In the meantime you can use this query as a workaround:

WITH step1 AS
(
    SELECT brightness, IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId as deviceid
    FROM input
)

SELECT
LAG(brightness, 1, -1) 
OVER (PARTITION BY deviceid  LIMIT DURATION(minute, 10)) as lastBrightness
FROM step1